# Conditional eager loading nested relations for a polymorphic relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following models:

Post, Postable, Banner, Poll, Options and Votes.

The relations are as follow:

1 Post can have Many Postables
1 Postable can have either a banner or a poll (Polymorphic relationship)
1 Poll can have many answers
1 Answer can have many votes.

I would like to be able to load the contents of the postables and if the postable is poll, I would like to get the options and the votes on it.

I have tried to implement the following function using the following query

```
Post::with(['postables' => function ($query) {
                $query->with('postable.options.votes')
                      ->where('postable_type', 'poll');
            }, 'postables' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('postable_type', 'banner')->with('postable');
            }])->get()
```

I ony get the postables whose type is banner, how can i get the options and the votes as well as the banner in the same call

Comment: You don't see any issues with `['postables' => ..., 'postables' => ...]`? When you use the same Array key, the last one will overwrite any that come before it... So you end up with `['postables' => ...]`. You'll need to figure out how to either get all your rows in a single `postables` property, or define separate relationships for Polls and Banners.

Comment: Can you share what your models look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i needed to get the votes and the options with the poll every time, I went with the following solution.

```
public class Poll {

protected $with=['options.votes'];

...

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

You can consider doing like below:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;

Post::with(['postables' => function (MorphTo $morphTo) {
        $morphTo->morphWith([
            Poll::class => ['options.votes'],
        ]);
    }])->get();
```

Conference https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading-morphto-relationships